# Remove lines from stderr

Tags: shell-script, ssh, grep, stdout, stderr

There is custom message that comes each time I `ssh` or `scp` which I would like to hide. I still want the rest of the stderr to go to stderr output.

For example: `a.sh` contain one line: `ssh example.com "touch /tmp/a.log ; echo ok"`

```
myuser@host $ ./a.sh
No valid ciphers for protocol version 2 given, using defaults.
#######
# this is prod
#
#######
ok
myuser@host $
```

So I want to hide the first 5 lines, or if putting it into scripting `grep -v -E "#|No valid ciphers for protocol"`. Any other error should still be output to screen/stderr.

Comment: Why don't you tune your `ssh_config` instead?

Comment: This is only for certain scripts, alert should be present at most scripts but mainly for any login.

Comment: You can use custom config file as `ssh -F configfile`.

Comment: I don't wish to use custom file as my script may be run from different servers that have different configuration

Answer (score 2):

```
( exec 7>&1; your_command 2>&1 >&7 | grep -v msg_to_suppress >&2 )
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618078/pipe-only-stderr-through-a-filter.

Answer (score 0):

The banner message looks like it's set on the remote server. You should be able to supress it with `-q`:

```
ssh -q example.com ...
```

The cipher message can be suppressed by using a cipher that matches one of the set offered by the server. Start with `ssh -Q cipher` and then experiment with settings such as `ssh -o Cipher=aes256-gcm@openssh.com ...`